# Why i can't left click on my blog post?

Tags: javascript, html, css, blogs, blogger

I'm creating blogger template at first time.
Everything work correctly.

But ther is 1 problem
I can't left click on my blog post
I didn't install right/left click disabler
Anyone can help me? Maybe i lost some css

i know the blog post tag
this is some css

```
 .date-header {  font-size:14px;  font-weight:normal;  color:#CCC;  }  

 .post {  overflow:hidden;  float:left;  }  

 .post h3 {  font-size:22px;  font-weight:normal;  margin:0px;
  padding:0px;  line-height:1.6em;  }  

 .post blockquote {  font-style:normal;  font-size:13px;  padding:10px
 20px;  margin:5px 0px 5px 25px;  background:#F3F6F9;  border:1px solid #D8D8D8;  } 

 .post-footer{  padding:3px 8px;  font-size:11px;  background:#F5F5F5; 
  margin:10px 0 10px 0;  border:1px solid #E3E3E3;  } 

 .post-body {  padding:10px 25px 0px 0;  } 

 .post-body h2 { font-size:16px; font-weight:normal; margin:0px; 
  padding:0px; line- height:1.6em; } 

 .post-body ul { font-size:12px;  line-height:18px;  padding-left:12px
 } 

 .post-body ol{ list-style-type:decimal;  line-height:18px; 
 margin:0px; 
 padding:0px 0px 10px 35px
 } 

 .post-body ul{
   list-style:none; 
   line-height:18px; 
   margin:0px; 
   padding:0px 0px 10px 0px
 } 

 .post-body li{
   margin:0px; padding:0px
 } 
 .post-body ul li{
   list-style:disc outside; 
   line-height:18px; 
   margin:0px 30px 0px 30px; 
   padding:5px 0px 0px 0
 }
```

I only can left click on the blog post date sometimes at first 2 second loading the blog, I can left click, but after that i can't left click. Anything is wrong?

This is the [zone](http://rivadotaku.blogspot.com/2014/01/cara-menggunakan-single-player-commands.html)

Comment: probably some js error is occuring . did you take a look at the javascript console?

Comment: @anurupr , thanks for answering, finally i know the problem source! But i don't know what  Js. Do you know something about that javascript? I'm noob :D

Answer (score 0):

You need to remove position: relative from your H1, H2, H3, H4 tags. If you inspect your H3 at the top of your first post, and remove the relative - it allows you to then select your text.

Comment: Seems to be part of this CSS file: https://www.blogger.com/static/v1/widgets/3160349130-widget_css_2_bundle.css

Comment: i think the right answer is Js error. Do you want to help me, please? I will send you the XML

Comment: Finally the problem is on related post javascripts. 



thanks for answering! snowbeluga and anurupr!